# Ошибка: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Вот такую ошибку выдает:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Что я не так сделал?

```
var map = new Array(26, 26);

for (var q = 0; q < 26; q++) {
    if (q == 25) {
        for (var w = 0; w < 26; w++) {
            map[q][w] = 'f';
        }
    } else {
        for (var w = 0; w < 25; w++) {
            map[q][w] = 'e';
        }
        map[q][w] = 'f';
    }
}
alert(map[0][0]);
```

Comment: @Макс Кожанов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: ага, спасибо

Comment: please, Help me!!!

Comment: `var map = new Array(26, 26);` это не двумерный массив, как вы могли подумать, а всего лишь массив из 2-х чисел

Comment: @Spectre, кто из нас первый, как узнать?

Comment: оба первые :)

Comment: @karmadro4, вы привели отличную ссылку, тем самым заслужив ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно инициализируете массив. Конструктор с *двумя* аргументами создаст одномерный массив [26, 26], а не матрицу 26×26 заполненную `undefined`, что предполагает данный код.

Зее альзо [справочник от мозиллы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Ничего, если я приведу пример решения проблемы?

var a=new Array (10);


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
  a[i]=new Array (10);

  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
   a[i][j] = i*10 + j;
  }
    }

С сайта: http://www.gnuman.ru/stuff/js/array

Comment: не используйте `new Array()`! просто `var a = [];`

Comment: А мне больше нравится дисциплинированный метод с явным заданием длины.

Comment: я не пытаюсь переубедить, просто ИМХО:

    var ARRAY_LENGTH = 10;// допустим, константа
    var array = new Array(ARRAY_LENGTH);
    for(var i = array.length;i--;){...}
    
    // эквивалентно
    var array = [];
    for(var i = ARRAY_LENGTH;i--;){...}    

я заметил, что у вас явная симпатия к конструкторам `Number(), Array(), etc.`=) 

хотя многие рекомендуют именно литеральную запись

Comment: @Spectre, здесь *нравится* потому, что более декларативно. С константой тоже ничего, но оставляет привкус незавершенности; по-моему надо идти дальше и делать полем объекта наследующего от этого массива.

А `Number.constructor` я люблю потому, что он делает неспецифичное преобразование в `Number`, в отличии от специфичных `parseXXX` :-)